# Get base colours percentage from base colours

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb, cmyk

Basically I'm trying to create a printer which print colours using 3 cartridges as base colours; let's call them A,B and C.

Machine operating:
The machine mix an amount of each cartridge to get a new color (the sum of all the amounts should be 100). This new color can be seen as an RGB value.

The question is: How can I get the percentage of each base colour (the amount of each cartridge) from an RGB value to mix that colour? It doesn't matter if the percentage is not exact.

I created a table with some examples of the machine operation, the base colours are highlighted (This table doesn't contains the real examples, it's just for explanation).

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: The table above was only for explain the whole structure. 
So basically I'm trying to simulate how a printer works, I have 3 customs cartridges and I need to print a custom colour, for example a red image, and don't know which percentage of each colour I need to set up for matching the red image. That makes sense?

Comment: @JanneKarila Maybe that should work but don't know how to set up the equations properly.

Comment: @JanneKarila I would rather go *Curve Fitting*

Comment: @A.S.H Curve Fitting looks really useful. Would you mind to explain a bit more about it? Thanks.

Comment: say A is a linear combination of Red, Green and Blue. You have many sample points, so you fit your best fit line using the *Least Square* method. You apply the same for B and C. You might also find that a second order polynomial might better fit your data, it needs some investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) ?

you can train a network giving 3 inputs as training data and then execute it on your work. It supports more than 20 programming languages so I think it will be easy to integrate ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly ...

Split each RGB colour into components.
R is a component.
G is a component.
B is a component.

Now you just have to add the 3 red components to get their maximum value; you now multiply by 100 and divide by 255; this should give you the percentage for the red component.
Same about green component and blue component.

Well, that's for the "getting the percentage of a base colour" part.
Making the sum become 100% is just a matter of dividing 300 by the sum of the 3 individual percentages (this can of course be shortened by dividing 3*255 by the sum of the individual components), then multiplying each component-percentage or each component by that value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone.

I finally ended up using FANN neural network http://leenissen.dk

Using fann_cascadetrain_on_data, with 3 inputs (R-G-B), 3 outputs (A,B,C) and using the set of examples as training data.

Thanks.